# matching multiple terms using match_phrase - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to fetch two documents that fit on the params searched, searching by each document separately works fine.

The query:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {
               "match_phrase":{
                  "email":"elpaso"
               }
            },
            {
               "match_phrase":{
                  "email":"walker"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Im expecting to retrieve both documents that have these words in their email address field, but the query is only returning the first one `elpaso`

Is this an issue related to index mapping? I'm using type `text` for this field.

Any concept I am missing?

Index mapping:

```
{

    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "name":{
            "type": "text"
          },
          "email":{
            "type" : "text"
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

Sample data:

```
{
   "id":"4a43f351-7b62-42f2-9b32-9832465d271f",
   "name":"Walker, Gary (Mr.) .",
   "email":"walkergrym@mail.com"
}


{
   "id":"1fc18c05-da40-4607-a901-3d78c523cea6",
   "name":"Texas Chiropractic Association P.A.C.",
   "email":"txchiro@mail.com"
}

{
   "id":"9a2323f4-e008-45f0-9f7f-11a1f4439042",
   "name":"El Paso Energy Corp. PAC",
   "email":"elpaso@mail.com"
}
```

I also noticed that if I use `elpaso` and `txchiro` instead of `walker` the query works as expected!

noticed that the issue happens, when I use only parts of the field. If i search by the exact entire email address, everything works fine.

is this expected from `match_phrase`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting any result from `walker` because elasticsearch uses a `standard` analyzer if no analyzer is specified which will tokenize `walkergrym@mail.com` as

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "walkergrym@mail.com"
}
```

The following token will be generated

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "walkergrym",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "mail.com",
      "start_offset": 11,
      "end_offset": 19,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

**Since there is no token for `walker` you are not getting `"walkergrym@mail.com"` in your search result.**

Whereas for `"txchiro@mail.com"`, token generated are `txchiro` and `mail.com` and for `"elpaso@mail.com"` tokens are `elpaso` and `mail.com`

You can use the [`edge_ngram tokenizer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html), to achieve your required result

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 6,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "email": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "email": "elpaso"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "email": "walker"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66907434",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 3.9233165,
        "_source": {
          "id": "4a43f351-7b62-42f2-9b32-9832465d271f",
          "name": "Walker, Gary (Mr.) .",
          "email": "walkergrym@mail.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66907434",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 3.9233165,
        "_source": {
          "id": "9a2323f4-e008-45f0-9f7f-11a1f4439042",
          "name": "El Paso Energy Corp. PAC",
          "email": "elpaso@mail.com"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: yeah, its weird. I've added my index mapping to the question, think everything is all right with it?

Comment: @queroga_vqz there is no issue with index mapping. Can you please share your sample index data ?

Comment: thank you for your time @ESCoder, added the sample data, and also another working case

Comment: @queroga_vqz please go through the updated answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Perfect. Didnt know about how ES worked on top of standard tokenizer. Thanks a lot for the lesson!